# Firefox versus Python: latest version versus frozen version

Tags: updates

Periodically, Ubuntu prompts me to download the latest version of Firefox.  But some programs, like Python, are never upgraded unless you update Ubuntu itself.  For instance, Ubuntu 14.04 uses Python 2.7.6, despite the fact that 2.7.7 came out years ago.  Is there any particular logic as to which things get constantly updated versus which get frozen?

Comment: [Newer versions of Firefox](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) are provided via security updates, not quite constant update by itself.

Comment: Not sure this answers my question.  The fact is, Python 2.7.12 also has bug fixes and security updates on top of Python 2.7.6.  Why the different policy?  The whole thing that prompted this question is that Ubuntu 16.04 has a version of Octave which has a bug that was quickly fixed in the next version, but the buggy version is "locked".

Comment: I'd think the logic like this: Those packages are available from different repositories, which are handled by different maintainers, hence different priorities to update the packages. E.g. Python and Firefox are from `main` but Octave is from `universe`.

Comment: But I'm seeing the opposite!  Python and Octave seem to have the same update policy, which is totally different than Firefox's policy.